# How to show specific array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 

$XMLContent=file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"); 

foreach($XMLContent as $line){ 
        if(preg_match("/rate='([[:graph:]]+)'/",$line,$rate)){ 
            echo "$rate[1]<br>"; 
        } 
 } 
?>
```

but the result are displayed all,my question that displaying data in the first row

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to stop the loop after the first match:

```
foreach($XMLContent as $line){ 
    if(preg_match("/rate='([[:graph:]]+)'/",$line,$rate)){ 
        echo "$rate[1]<br>"; 
        break;
    } 
}
```